# Showing that $\lim_{x \to1} \log(x)= 0$

Tags: limits, proof-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

We are trying to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \space \exists \delta>0 \space 0<|x-1|<\delta \Rightarrow |log(x)| < \epsilon$

My attempt:

Notice that if $|\log(x)| < \epsilon \Rightarrow -\epsilon < \log(x) < \epsilon \Rightarrow e^{-\epsilon} - 1 < x-1 < e^{\epsilon} - 1$.

Proof.

Take $\delta = e^{\epsilon} - 1$. We know that $0<|x-1|<\delta \Rightarrow x-1 < \delta \Rightarrow x < \delta + 1$. Now consider $|f(x)| = |\log(x)| < \log(\delta + 1) = \log(e^{\epsilon} + 1 - 1) = \epsilon $, as required.

Is this correct? I feel like I'm missing something, since $e^{-\epsilon} - 1$ can also be $\delta$.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$ ?

Comment: What is $f(x)$?

Comment: Why are you taking $0<|x-1|<\delta$? You are not doing a limit of the form $\lim\limits_{x\to1}f(x)$. Likewise, you are not taking the limit of $\log(x)$, but rather $e^x$. You want to show that $|e^x-1|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I'm sorry the title was supposed to read "$lim_{x\to1}log(x) = 0$"

Comment: What's your definition of $\log(x)$?

Comment: $log(x) = ln(x)$.

Comment: Yes, but how do you define $\ln(x)$?

Comment: You can define it as a logarithm to the base of $e$?

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

Set $x=e^u$. When $x\to 0$, then $u\to 0$, and thus $$\lim_{x\to 1}\log(x)=\lim_{u\to 0}\log(e^{u})=\lim_{u\to 0}u=0.$$

**Method 2**

$\log$ can be defined as $$\log(x)=\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt.$$
By the fundamental theorem of analysis, $$x\longmapsto \int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt$$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, and thus $$\lim_{x\to 1}\log(x)=0.$$